# Difference between total specialization and disjoint rule in dbms?

Tags: database

Both are looking same to me. i am not getting the exact deference. i search on different forums and sites but not getting clear.  what is the difference between them?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a total specialization, in the example shown, a patient must be either a outpatient or a resident patient, which means that all patients needs to be one of the sub types(outpatient or resident).

The disjoint rule is different in the way that a patient needs to be in only one subtype.

Basically, as I understand, the difference is that the total specialization says a super type needs to be in a sub type and the disjoint says it need to be in only one sub type.

I hope this helps.

There is a link that you can read about all these types and rules:
http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=subclass.php

Answer (score 3):

The exact difference is as follows. You have to first separate the total/partial participation constraints to understand this better and we'll take them into account later on.

**Disjoint Constraint**

Any instance can map to at most one subclass. Not more than that. e.g Bank Account can be either 'Savings Account' or 'Current Account' not both. So when the database is operational, every given instance will be mapped to exactly one subclass defined under the super class. Another example would a meal will be mapped to either Veg or Non-veg..It can't be both.

**Partial Constraint**

Any instance may or may not map to multiple sub classes of a given super class. This usually happens when an instance play multiple roles and not limited to a single one. e.g Employee may map to either supervisor, manager or both. This means an employee can play both the roles of a manager and a supervisor. Another example would be a musician who maybe mapping to either violin player, guitar player, flutist,saxophonist or all of them.

**Note:**
So when you specify an 'ISA' relationship your subclasses may behave in either disjoint way or overlap way.. They can't be both, meaning that Disjoint is the exact opposite of Overlap constraint.

Now let's focus on Total and Partial constraints.

Regardless of the overlapping/disjoint constraints, total/partial mean 'do all the instances support the specialization?' question. So when the database is operational and if your ISA relationship is total, any instance coming will be directed to one of the sub classes  and nothing will stay in the super class. Conversely, if it's partial, some instances may not have an appropriate subclass so they will stay in the super class.

This brings up the interesting notions as follows.

**Total-Disjoint**-  All the instances coming, will map to one subclass only and will not be shared among other subclasses

**Partial-Disjoint**- All instances coming, may stay with superclass or map to one of the sub classes only

**Total-Overlap**- All instances coming, will map to multiple subclasses.

**Partial-Overlap**- All instances coming, may stay with the super class or map to multiple sub classes.

Answer (score 2):

Total Participation vs Partial Participation.
In total participation, patient must be an outpatient or resident patient, it can not simply be the superclass patient type. Partial participation allows you to have a patient be just a patient.

Under Total specialization, there can be no entities that are of a superclass but are not of any of the subclasses. This is represented by the double line drawn from patient

Disjoint means a subclass type patient can be either an outpatient or resident patient but not both. Subclasses can only be one subclass from the superclass not both.

So in both diagrams a patient must be a one of the subclasses, but the disjoint means it can not be both subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different decisions {Total participation vs Partial participation} and {Disjoint vs Overlap}.

Participation -> ∈ {subclass1,..,subclassN} vs ∈ {subclass1,..,subclassN, superclass}

Subclass Type -> ∈ {S1 xor S2 xor ... xor SN} vs ∈ {S1 or S2 or ... or SN}
where S is the entities.